# Cycling through workspaces in multi monitor setup in XMonad

Tags: multiple-monitors, xmonad, xmonad-contrib

I'm currently using <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>right</kbd> to cycle between workspaces:

```hs
...

    , ((altModMask .|. controlMask, xK_Left),
      prevWS)
    , ((altModMask .|. controlMask, xK_Right),
      nextWS)
```

This works fine for single monitor setup. However it is a bit confusing when using a dual monitor setup. This is because the workspace to be shown will change screen if currently visible on another screen. For instance if I have ws 1 on screen 0 and ws 2 on screen 1 and have the focus on screen 0:

```
1:term (2:web) 3:txt
```

When I now do a `nextWS`, ws 2, that was currently on screen 1 will be drawn to screen 0, while screen 1 will show ws 1.

```
(1:term) 2:web 3:txt
```

What I would like is a behaviour where `prexWS` and `nextWS` will ***jump over*** the workspace that is currently shown on the other monitor and only select a workspace that is currently not shown.

Are there such commands already or is there some `xmonad.hs` example that implements this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`XMonad.Actions.DynamicWorkspaceOrder`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Actions-DynamicWorkspaceOrder.html) from the `xmonad-contrib`:

```hs
import qualified XMonad.Actions.DynamicWorkspaceOrder as DO

...

    , ((altModMask .|. controlMask, xK_Left),
      DO.moveTo Prev HiddenNonEmptyWS)
    , ((altModMask .|. controlMask, xK_Right),
      DO.moveTo Next HiddenNonEmptyWS)
```

Comment: Note that you need to import `XMonad.Actions.CycleWS` for `HiddenNonEmptyWS`.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you asked for, but here's a version of [`cycleRecentNonEmptyWS`](https://xmonad.github.io/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Actions-CycleRecentWS.html#v:cycleRecentNonEmptyWS) that skips over the workspaces that are visible on the other monitors:

```hs
import Data.Maybe (isJust)
import XMonad
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
import XMonad.Actions.CycleRecentWS (cycleWindowSets, recentWS)

cycleRecentHiddenNonEmptyWS :: [KeySym] -> KeySym -> KeySym -> X ()
cycleRecentHiddenNonEmptyWS mods keyNext keyPrev = do
  pred <- getPred
  cycleWindowSets (recentWS pred) mods keyNext keyPrev
  where
    -- Based on private function @wsTypeToPred@ in
    -- @Xmonad.Actions.CycleWS@. Select workspaces that are non-empty
    -- and not on another screen.
    getPred :: X (WindowSpace -> Bool)
    getPred = withWindowSet $ \ws -> do
      -- The hidden windows don't include the currently focused
      -- window, which means we can't abort once we start cycling. So,
      -- instead, we define "hidden" as "focused or not visible". The
      -- @W.visible@ screens are the non-focused but visible ones.
      let visibles = map (W.tag . W.workspace) $ W.visible ws
      let hidden w = W.tag w `notElem` visibles
      let nonEmpty w = isJust (W.stack w)
      return (\w -> hidden w && nonEmpty w)
```

You can use it just like `cycleRecentNonEmptyWS`, e.g. by adding this to your key map:

```hs
             -- The 'xK_grave' is backtick ("`"), so tab cycles
             -- forward, and backtick cycles back.
             , ((modm, xK_Tab), cycleRecentHiddenNonEmptyWS [xK_Super_L] xK_Tab xK_grave)
```